# How to close intent opened on startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, back

My app uses accessibility, i have opened the intent with `startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS),500);` and handled result `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {}` but the problem the accessibility intent is not returning /self closing back to my app which promoted me to use `finish()` to act like am pressing back key button but no avail... whats the solution ?

Comment: You aren't clear about what exactly you are trying to do, are you trying to go back/finish when the result comes in? if so have you checked to see if the `resultCode` is triggered?

Comment: I want to close ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS window it's on top of my app